# Nginx not displaing Phoenix web app

Tags: nginx, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to deploy a basic Phoenix app to a DigitalOcean server running ubuntu 14.04. I'm using exrm to generate the release. The release works when I test it on my local machine and on the server. I'm following the Phoenix guides on  [deployment](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/advanced-deployment). The thing that doesn't seem to work is the last part with the nginx server setup. For some reason I cant get it to load anyting but the default page. When I run the

> nginx -t # command. It says everything is fine.

I've tried editing the /etc/nginx/sites-available files. Doesn't seem to do anything. I've tried restarting the nginx server with

> sudo service nginx reload
>   sudo service nginx restart

But that doesn't seem to work either.
And this is the content of my /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_app.conf

```
upstream my_app {
server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}

server{
listen 80;
server_name www.example.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;
}

location @proxy {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://my_app;
    # The following two headers need to be set in order
    # to keep the websocket connection open. Otherwise you'll see
    # HTTP 400's being returned from websocket connections.
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
```

}

Update: Tried connecting directly via server_ip:port, and it worked. The url still doesnt display anything.

Solved: For some reason deleting this solves the problem.:

`proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;`

Comment: Something I found out today while deploying Phoenix, is that when running in `MIX_ENV=prod` (which the exrm release will probably do), the default config settings do not specify a port (Rather, they wan to read the env `PORT` variable), Maybe this is the case here?

Comment: I specified 4000 as the port variable so that probably not it.

Comment: Did you mean to use `proxy_pass http://email_bot;` instead of `proxy_pass http://my_app;`?

Comment: Didn't change anything after I fixed it.

Comment: You mention `/etc/nginx/sites-available`. What about `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`?

Comment: I simlinked them as stated in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: For some reason deleting this solves the problem.

```
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
```